# How to extend an existing partition with newly installed hard drive

Tags: partitioning

My hard drive space almost running out, so I installed a new hard drive. My question is, Can I extend an existing patition with newly installed hard drive?
e.g.
Existing
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
/dev/sda3

new hard drive
/dev/sdb1

Can I extend /dev/sda2 with /dev/sdb1

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Since your partitions are showing up as `/dev/sda*`, that means you're using them directly. A physical partition is inherently part of a single disk, so you can't do it directly.

However, it is possible to create a *logical* partition that spans multiple physical drives, using [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29). LVM can be set up using the Ubuntu installer, but since you already have a working installation you would need to set it up manually. If you have a separate `/home` partition, this isn't too difficult:

1. From a live CD, back up your `/home` partition (e.g. using `dd` or partimage) to somewhere else.
2. Format the old `/home` partition and `/dev/sdb1` as LVM physical volumes. If you want more space for the root as well, delete the `/home` partition and recreate it smaller.
3. Add the two physical volumes to an LVM volume group.
4. Create a new LVM volume using all available space.
5. Restore your image onto the new volume. Expand the partition to fill the entire space using `resize2fs`.
6. Adjust your fstab to tell it to automatically mount your logical partition.

Beware: You will lose the logical partition if *either* disk fails. Keep good backups.